# Add more options while flagging a question

Tags: feature-request, flags

As we can see Stack Overflow has removed some good options for flagging like

1. Too localized
2. Not a real question

Why is it necessary to remove some flags if you have to add others? I am seeing some new options but they lack some specifics. Here I suggest a new flagging option

Example:

**Insufficient question information** - Most of Stack Overflow questions do not contain enough data to solve questions. Can we have this kind of option? It will be of great help for other users who like to answer for them but they can't because they don't get proper details about the question.

Comment: There's an "Unclear" reason, and two variations of off-topic close reasons, one of which will usually apply.

Comment: Were there...any other options you wanted to suggest? I only see 1 listed there.

Comment: Yes, This is what I do, but It would be good to either rename it or you can add a new one

Comment: @CodyGray - I liked it, I've a lot of suggestions for flagging

Comment: We can add more sites for off topic questions

Comment: Yeah. How about InsufficientData.StackExchange.com? (I would not join.)

Comment: :/ Nobody will never propose such a proposal on Area51

Comment: You can also ask OP for clarification if the question does not contain enough data. Just putting this out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is already a matching reason for this in the flag box. Under the second radio item when flagging a question (it doesn't belong here, or it is a duplicate…) you will find this:

> **unclear what you're asking**
>   Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

That is the option you should be selecting to flag questions that do not yet have enough data to answer properly.

Once you earn a bit more reputation, you will actually be able to Vote to Close (VTC) questions for this exact reason instead of having a moderator or high rep user review your flag and possibly cast a vote themselves.

Comment: Yes, this is the final option we have, I just wanted it to be more clear like - Insufficient question information , anyways it is just fine, I just wanted to give a suggestion Now it is upto moderators.

Comment: @VegetarianVulture In the case you are suggesting "more clear" basically means "more specific", but by making the wording more specific you would invalidate the close reason for a lot of other cases that weren't quite the same. Keep in mind these close reasons are standardized across the entire network of 100+ sites so they have to be at least a little bit generic. A comment requesting the specific piece of missing data would be better than trying to make the generic close reason too specific.

Comment: And why we can't flag a question if it is too localized

Comment: @VegetarianVulture The flag reasons are one-for-one compatible with the close reasons. A question cannot be closed as "too localized" any more, there is no such option. Some sites have something similar as a sub-option under off-topic, in which case you can flag as off topic. Remember a flag is submitting the question to review by somebody else who will have to make a judgement call about what to do with it, including picking a VTC reason.